# Filter using Underscore - roots and children

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Well, it's probably very basic for experienced ppl. It's my 1st time with underscore. I've this json.

```
{
    "especiais" : {
        "text" : {
            "pt" : "Especiais"
        },
        "active" : true
    },
    "conjuntos" : {
        "text" : {
            "pt" : "Conjuntos"
        },
        "active" : true,
        "subItems" : {
            "saiaEcamiseta" : {
                "text" : {
                    "pt" : "Saia e Camiseta"
                },
                "active" : true
            },
            "sandalhas" : {
                "text" : {
                    "pt" : "Sandalhas"
                },
                "active" : true
            }
        }
    },
    "macacoes" : {
        "text" : {
            "pt" : "Macacões"
        },
        "active" : true
    },
    "roupasBasicas" : {
        "text" : {
            "pt" : "Roupas Básicas"
        },
        "active" : true,
        "subItems" : {
            "xortes" : {
                "text" : {
                    "pt" : "Xortes"
                },
                "active" : true
            },
            "camiseta" : {
                "text" : {
                    "pt" : "Camisetas"
                },
                "active" : true
            }
        }
    },
    "enxoval" : {
        "text" : {
            "pt" : "Enxoval"
        },
        "active" : true
    }
```

}

And I want to list only active roots of itens and subitems. So, in the example above, macacoes and his children will not be listed and Xortes (child of roupasBasicas) will not be listed as well and it's includes possible grandchildren if appliable.

I made my 1st attempt:

```
    result = _und.filter(data.productCategories, function (item) {
        return item && item.active.indexOf(true) != -1;
    });
```

but it's not working :( Can anybody help me ?

Comment: why would macacoes not be shown?

Comment: because we need to assume that active in this item is false.

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of reputation I cannot ask for clarification so I will take my best stab at an answer for you.

```
var children = [];

//Get all of the subitems that are active so we can merge with the primary result set
_.each(data.pt, function(item){
  if(item.subItems){
    _.each(item.subItems, function(child){
      if(child.active) children.push(child);
    });
  }
}); 

//Gather all active items in the primary result set
var result = _.filter(data.pt, function(item){
  return item.active;
});

//Add each active subItem to our results
_.each(children, function(child){
  result.push(child);
});
```

Here is a plunkr of my understanding: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/qx6U6ZcmcfhqJxmNulzP?p=preview
-- Take a look at the script.js since it will provide the core implementation.

From my understanding you wanted to gather all "active" items within the context of that pt object?

If that is the case, the filter I provide via the link will be fine though you will still have the items underneath the parent.

If those need to be filtered you could simply null out the field that attaches that data to the object (or more clever ways if you so choose).

The `_.filter` function seems the best fit for this since you are allowed to filter a dataset given a predicate. The function in the second part of the query I provided in aforementioned code narrows the scope of the original data set down based on whether or not they are active.

Comment: Hey, Matt ! Reading again...my explanation was very bad, but you god my point anyway ! Well, it's almost 100% correct. Your sentence can hide items where active = false on the root, but it's must display all the children as well and of course: can't display children where active = false.

Comment: In other words...it's a category tree where I need to hide inactive categories and subcategories - to clarify. ty !!!

Comment: I think I see what you're talking about now. If you are guaranteed that the subItems will not nest indefinitely then the updated answer may work for you.

I also updated the plunk.